# Medibo javascript getcontacts : AUTHFAIL

Tags: mesibo

I have set up https://github.com/mesibo/messenger-javascript but user and group names not came which I have created in the admin console.

With this setup, anyone can join with mobile and OTP but I have to restrict the users. How can we meet do that.

If I put user auth token in config.js {op: "getcontacts", error: "AUTHFAIL", result: "FAIL"}

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WhatsApp, do you expect WhatsApp to load all their billions of users and groups to your phone? No, right?

What you create in the mesibo admin console is a list of all the users and groups of your app. Your users should NOT get access to all. You should selectly load required users and groups and show it in your javascript as per your application logic.

I suggest you read https://mesibo.com/documentation/tutorials/get-started/ first to understand how mesibo works before jumping to that messenger app.